# Efficient way to load HTML and bind View Modal inside wizard-like process

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

For the signup process on a site I'm developing, the user will interact through a modal window (bootstrap modal) that acts similar to a Wizard - going step to step.  Each step is a small form, and there is logic for branching between steps.  There are currently 14 total steps, but the longest chain a user would go through is 5 steps.

I am using knockout to bind each form to a view model, and during the step transition, I save the relevant data from the form.

Currently, I have each step as a small view in ASP.NET MVC, and I am using jQuery's load method to pull the step down to the client as it runs, putting it into the .modal-body div on my bootstrap modal.  I then bind the view model to the .modal-body element.  However, I end up having to perform a ko.cleanNode first, as the modal-body div is already bound.

This seems inefficient to me - between the HTTP requests for each step, and having to unbind then rebind.  I was thinking I could instead build the entire HTML structure once in MVC using hidden divs, return that, bind the entire view model, and then just show/hide each step as necessary.  This would be how I would accomplish the goal if it was all on a single page.  That initial html load seems excessive, though, given that a majority of steps are not used.

Are either of my attempts sound, and are there other ways to accomplish this that would perform better?  By perform better, I mean less HTTP requests and less binding complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it once, it's not really that inefficient at all. Then use Knockout to show/hide the various steps. Servers are really good at shipping HTML to their clients.

Comment: A small but important detail is to show/hide the steps using an if-binding, and not a visible-binding. The initial sending of the HTML might be fast, but if all those nodes are added to the DOM WITH bindings applied, it can make the page a lot heavier on the client. By using the if-binding, performance won't suffer much at all, and there's no downside that I'm aware of within this context.

Comment: Agreed. One larger HTTP request is less complicated (in both DOM handling and number of requests). Trying to save a few kb on an initial HTTP call (that has to be made anyway; the real work) will get you nothing performance wise.